# Converting Sql query to CodeIgniter Active Records

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanted to query only those items that have a highest likes.

This is the sql query I want to convert into CodeIgnitor's Active Records:

```
SELECT *, SUM(like) as totalLikes
FROM tbl_like
GROUP BY uploadID
ORDER BY totalLikes DESC
LIMIT 2
```

**CodeIgniter:**

```
public function get_cheezyPic(){
      $this->db->select('uploadID, SUM(like) as totalLikes');
      $this->db->from('tbl_like');
      $this->db->group_by('uploadID');
      $this->db->order_by('totalLikes DESC');
      $this->db->limit(2);

      $query= $this->db->get();

      return $query->result_array();}
```

But when I try to run this code, I've got this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like) as totalLikes FROM (`tbl_like`) GROUP BY `uploadID` ORDER BY `totalLikes` ' at line 1

```
SELECT `uploadID`, SUM(like) as totalLikes FROM (`tbl_like`) GROUP BY `uploadID` ORDER BY `totalLikes` desc LIMIT 2
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll work for you. Please note that you were using reserved keyword so it should be enclosed with **backtic** **``**.

```
public function get_cheezyPic(){
      $this->db->select('uploadID, SUM(`like`) as totalLikes',false);
      $this->db->from('tbl_like');
      $this->db->group_by('uploadID');
      $this->db->order_by('totalLikes DESC');
      $this->db->limit(2);

      $query= $this->db->get();

      return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: @Jen143Me Ihave updated the query you can check as `like` is reserved keyword it needs to be quoted

Comment: Yeah,,it is working now but I how will I display the total likes?

Comment: Are you getting value within it

Comment: I just do like this `<?php echo $cheezy1['like']?>` .

Comment: In the table, the field like has a value of 1,,then in my query I sum up all the likes of all the same as uploadID

Comment: No its not it that manner you need to use `<?php echo $cheezy1['totalLikes']?>` this is why you have used an alias

Comment: The value displayed by 'totalLikes' is 0

Comment: If you place the query within sql whats the result and I've  updated my answer